# When i Try to run an simple android apps in eclipse, then it showing me an installation error : unknown failure, what should i do?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

1. [2015-09-19 10:14:19 - Test] Android Launch!<>

   [2015-09-19 10:14:19 - Test] adb is running normally.

   [2015-09-19 10:14:19 - Test] Performing
   com.example.test.MainActivity activity launch

   [2015-09-19 10:14:19 - Test] Automatic Target Mode: using existing
   emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'MyDevice2'

   [2015-09-19 10:14:19 - Test] Uploading Test.apk onto device
   'emulator-5554'

   ****[2015-09-19 10:14:24 - Test] Installing Test.apk...**

   [2015-09-19 10:15:58 - Test] Installation error: Unknown failure

   [2015-09-19 10:15:58 - Test] Please check logcat output for more
   details.

   [2015-09-19 10:16:01 - Test] Launch canceled!**

   [2015-09-19 10:16:55 - Test] ------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

Add your code also.. May be this is due to your emulator or device is not properly constructed to run the app..

Answer (score 0):

try to reboot your computer
if nothing happen try this 
1. Run Configurations - Common - Select File In Standard Input And Output
2. Click Workspace And Choose Your Project.
3. Click Run.

Comment: are you sure using the latest  version of SDK with your android phone?maybe you had not waited long enough for the Android phone to load, so couldn't install anything on the simulator.

Comment: Thanks Dear, i get the solution,